# What are the alternatives for checking open ports, besides telnet?

Tags: linux, networking, curl, telnet

We can use the following in order to test telnet VIA port; in the following example we test port 6667:

```
[root@kafka03 ~]# telnet kafka02 6667
Trying 103.64.35.86...
Connected to kafka02.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host
```

Since on some machines we can't use telnet (for internal reasons) what are the alternatives to check ports, as telnet?

Comment: Is perl an option?

Comment: Those "internal reasons" might bar you from using other port-scanning software. I knew a guy that worked at a bank and had his contract terminated because he had a copy of nmap on his PC. He was using it for work-related purposes, but it was on the proscribed list, so he was escorted out of the building.

Comment: Is perl an option? – YES

Comment: Note that telnet is a sophisticated protocol. The `telnet` utility turns off the protocol behaviour if a port is given at command line. Then it behaves much like `netcat`, just with line ending detection.

Comment: A more operating-system agnostic question, that does not even hint at port scanning, is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/499694/ .

Answer (score 115, accepted):

[Netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) (`nc`) is one option.

```
nc -zv kafka02 6667
```

- `-z` = sets nc to simply scan for listening daemons, without actually sending any data to them
- `-v` = enables verbose mode

Comment: is it possible to get standard output from the nc ? because I want to write in in my bash script

Comment: Read the documentation! Without options `nc` behaves a lot like `telnet`.

Comment: yes I read the docs but -w flag not works as timeout

Comment: example - c -v  -w 1 kafka01  6667 ( we not get timeout )

Comment: nc -v  -w 3   kafka01  6667
Ncat: Version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 10.164.235.85:6667.  ( this still hang )

Comment: ncat is not netcat.

Answer (score 53):

If using Bash Shell, then you can use its feature to check if a port is open or closed:

```
(timeout 1 bash -c '</dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/17500 && echo PORT OPEN || echo PORT CLOSED') 2>/dev/null
PORT OPEN

(timeout 1 bash -c '</dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/7500 && echo PORT OPEN || echo PORT CLOSED') 2>/dev/null
PORT CLOSED
```

Note that if the server does not respond after 1 second the timeout is reached, the commands between `'` interrupted, and thus nothing is printed.

Comment: Perhaps you should use the hostname from the question (kafka02) instead of `127.0.0.1`, which makes it look like it only works with the loopback.

Comment: `(timeout 1 bash -c '</dev/tcp/www.google.com/444 && echo PORT OPEN || echo PORT CLOSED') 2>/dev/null` prints nothing for me. `(timeout 1 bash -c '</dev/tcp/www.google.com/444' && echo PORT OPEN || echo PORT CLOSED) 2>/dev/null` worked as expected (prints PORT CLOSED). Note the location of the `'`.

Comment: what you get on bash -c '</dev/tcp/kafka01/6667'

Comment: then echo $?  ( if 0 then port is open ,)

Comment: IIRC this bash feature used to be disabled in Debian some time ago. It's a neat trick but doesn't always work.

Comment: Both in2nix4life and thecarpy versions work.  It doesn't matter where the ' is

Comment: This worked great -- well it didn't print "PORT CLOSED" when it's closed but it does print "PORT OPEN" when it's open. Running on a dockerized Centos7 box. Anyway, exactly what I needed since `telnet` and `nc` were unavailable

Answer (score 35):

'curl' can make life easier. No root require ; curl is readily available on all the Linux systems:

1. If port is not open will show below output

   ```
   [niti@SourceServerName ~]$ curl -vv telnet://DestinationServerName:80

   * About to connect() to DestinationServerName port 80 (#0)
   *   Trying 192.168.0.100...
   ```
2. If port is open will show below output

   ```
   [niti@SourceServerName ~]$ curl -vv telnet://DestinationServerName:443

   * About to connect() to DestinationServerName port 443 (#0)
   *   Trying 192.168.0.100...
   * Connected to DestinationServerName (192.168.0.100) port 443 (#0)
   ```

<kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> to exit.

Comment: Why the extra v in "-vv"? I have not found any documentation that it does anything. Also, curl shows messages like "Connection refused" and "Could not resolve host" in regular (non-verbose) mode.

Comment: Good news: this also works out of the box in Windows 10 now.

Comment: this was the easiest and simplest for me. In my experience, for VMs behind k8s clusters it is not possible to install missing tools eg., telnet, nc etc., so curl came in quite handy. thank you!

Comment: Curl is absolutely not available on all linux systems, though it is available on most desktop distributions.

Answer (score 28):

The gold standard is undoubtedly `nmap` ([nmap.org](https://nmap.org)), but it typically requires root for “best results”. However, standalone binaries are available and it is possible to run it as an unprivileged user, just with degraded capabilities. For example, instead of a stealth `syn` scan (`-sS`), it falls back to a standard TCP connect scan (`-sT`). This is functionally equivalent to netcat, but with the nice multi-host, sped-up capabilities that it has.

An example:

```
not-root$ nmap -sT google.com
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-11-04 21:01 GMT
Nmap scan report for google.com (172.217.23.14)
Host is up (0.12s latency).
rDNS record for 172.217.23.14: lhr35s01-in-f14.1e100.net
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE
80/tcp  open  http
443/tcp open  https
```

Comment: in most organizations nmap is considered as a scaning tool and one can not use nmap without proper authorization. Also if it is an EC2 instance, authorization required from AWS as well.

Comment: do you really think a system where telnet isn't allowed would allow nmap?

Answer (score 8):

If Perl is an option, you can use its [`IO::Socket`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket) module to test a connection to a particular host and port; the script below hard-codes TCP as the protocol (which is what telnet would use):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# tries to connect to the given IP and port (tcp)

use strict;
use IO::Socket;

my $desthost = shift or die "Usage: $0 host port\n";
my $destport = shift or die "Usage: $0 host port\n";

gethostbyname($desthost) || die "Invalid host given\n";

my $handle = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        PeerAddr => $desthost,
        PeerPort => $destport,
        Proto    => 'tcp')
    or die "can't connect to $desthost:$destport: $!\n";
close $handle;
print "Success!\n"
```

Sample output from a closed port:

```
$ ./above-script kafka02 6667
can't connect to kafka02:6667: Connection refused
```

Sample output from an open port:

```
$ ./above-script kafka02 4200
Success!
```

Answer (score 4):

`openssl s_client -connect host:port`

Answer (score 3):

Device file /dev/tcp and /dev/udp can be used instead of telnet.
Example: `echo 0 > /dev/tcp/103.64.35.86/6667` . Then check the exit status using `echo $?` . If exit status is 0 then the port is open. If exit status is non-zero then the port is closed. For checking udp packets, use `echo 0 > /dev/udp/103.64.35.86/6667` .

Comment: in my redhat 7 under /dev/ , we not have tcp

Comment: ls  /dev/tcp/
ls: cannot access /dev/tcp/: No such file or directory

Comment: on which OS you test it?

Comment: @yael, you will not get /dev/tcp or /dev/udp while ls. try the exact same command on your shell and you will get the result. by the way, I frequently use it on RHEL6,7

Answer (score 2):

I found fast and simple this way, throgh Python interpreter (from https://serverfault.com/a/500062/168647):

```
[gryphius@ut ~]$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Feb 22 2013, 00:00:18) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                                                                                                                                                                                                         
>>> import socket                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
>>> conn=socket.create_connection(('gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com',25))
```

If that didn't throw an error so far the connection is ok.

Answer (score 1):

```
ss -lt
```

this is another command you can use.

Comment: It works only for local machine, I believe that question is about checking the open ports of a remote host.